# Unable to launch app from Xcode on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to launch an app from Xcode to my iPhone, but it is displaying the following error message :-

**Signing for "Lad" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.**

I have even tried and chosen the team as my Apple ID under signing and capabilities, but it's still not working.

Any Suggestions on how to eliminate this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose your Apple ID as your team.
2. Change the Bundle Identifier to something unique. If you are only developing the app for fun, you may type in gibberish. However, you will need an official Bundle Identifier (usually your company's identifier/email) if you are developing your app for professional reasons.
   (see image below)

[image: Image of where to input Bundle Identifier]

Hope this helps!